# How to pull data from datagridview to another form's textbox

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, textbox

I am trying to pull the data from a datagridview value in form1 to a textbox in form2 .

Form 1;

```
        public string xxx;
        public string GetX()
        {
            return xxx;
        }      

        private void addADocumentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                 
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows != null)
            {
                xxx = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();

                AddDocumentForm adf = new AddDocumentForm();
                adf.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose a record.");
                return;
            }
        }
```

In Form 2 trying to pull the xxx value into textbox;

```
using (Form1 f= new Form1())
            {                    
                string result= f.GetX();
                txtSavedDocumentID.Text = result;    
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Form2`, you are creating a new instance of `Form1`:

```
using (Form1 f= new Form1())
```

As I can't see your whole code, I might be wrong - but I think it is very likely that this is not what you want.

What you actually want is to call `GetX()` on an existing instance of `Form1`.

Now you need some way to know the correct instance of `Form1` on `Form2`. One easy possibility is, *but only if you will always just use one instance of `Form1`*, to expose a static property on `Form1` that will provide a singleton instance of it to the outside world:

```
public class Form1
{
    // ...

    public static readonly Form1 Instance {get; private set};

    public Form1()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

In `Form2`, instead of creating a new instance with your using statement, you'd access it like this:

```
string result = Form1.Instance.GetX();
txtSavedDocumentID.Text = result;
```

Now be aware that if your application has the possibility to have multiple instances of Form1 open, this won't work and will have bad side effects. In this case, another approach is needed. But I hope you got the idea now what might be wrong and you can work it out.

**Edit**: While this will solve your issue, hopefully, I want to add that it's not a very good approach having your Forms need to know about each other. You should have some model classes in the background where your Forms can read and write data on, without the need to interact with each other directly. But exploring this further would be out of scope of this question.

Comment: Basically I am trying to get selected value from datagridview row to a variable on Form1 then I want to use this value in Form2 when I open it.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it. But on Form2 you create a **new** Form2 instance - which means what you have in hand then is a completely "empty" Form2. It's not the same instance that you most likely created and showed to the user earlier.

You can try this to understand what I mean: on Form2, inside your using statement, show the Form1 on screen by `f.Show()` - you will see a completely new window pops up that has nothing to do with the From1 you wanted to get your variable from. It's a different window!

Comment: Sorry I noticed I mixed the Forms names up: My first sentence should be: But on Form2 you create a new **Form1** instance - which means what you have in hand then is a completely "empty" **Form1**.

Answer (score 0):

changed Form2 ;

```
public Form2(string qs)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = qs;
        }
```

In Form1;

get the text from combobox and pass it to form2 ;

```
 {
        var xxxx = (cbxEmployeeName.GetItemText(cbxEmployeeName.SelectedItem));
        Form2 f = new Form2(xxxx);
        f.Show();
    }
```